# Postman and Guzzle giving a different number of results

Tags: php, laravel, post, postman, guzzle

When I test a POST request in Postman, can see in it 167 results

[image]

Using Guzzle, can only see 100

```
$data = Http::post(url, [...]);

$data_decoded = json_decode($data);

dd($data_decoded);
```

[image]

How can I get all of the 167?

Comment: Look here : https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#expect it seems guzzle limits to 100 by default.
You can change the payload size if i understand.

Comment: Are you totally sure, that `objectId` exists once per array item? Is it possible that it was also additionally found in a nested entry in your arrayitems?
Just mentioning this, because you compare found entries in Guzzle and found properties in Postman.

Comment: @Tschitsch yes, I'm sure. Adding a `limit:5000` to the parameters, as @Hamham suggested initially, solved the problem

Comment: @Hamham you're welcome to write the answer

Comment: It's done :), happy it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can [read here](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#expect)

> By default, Guzzle will add the "Expect: 100-Continue" header when the size of the body of a request is greater than 1 MB and a request is using HTTP/1.1.

You can change the payload size. For instance, if you have that possibility, just pass a `limit` parameter like

```
$data = Http::post(url, [..., 'limit'=>300]);

$data_decoded = json_decode($data);

dd($data_decoded);
```